# Page navigation on Android using Basic4android

Tags: android, basic4android

I am new to Android programming. Using VB, how to navigate from one page to another page using Basic4android tool in www.basic4android.com

Code will be

```
startacticity("login")
```

Comment: A few remarks: please provide more details. As it is, I don’t think this question is really intelligible. Also, I’ve taken the liberty to format your question, and improve the title. Finally, I don’t think that Basic4android is quite the same as VB.NET (in fact, it looks completely different!) so I’m not sure that the tag is actually appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, Basic4Android uses Layouts rather than the typical VB Forms

So if you want to click a button to move from 1 layout to another, behind the 
click event you would have

```
Activity.LoadLayout("layoutname")
```

Answer (score 0):

To switch between activities on `Basic4Android`, you must enter the name of the activity in the code below.

```
StartActivity(LoginActivity)
```

Note that you should not include the name of an activity in Quotation mark .Name the activity without putting the mark.

I hope to help you